# Extracting the details of varied text formatting within a single SpreadsheetGear cell

Tags: c#, excel, text-formatting, spreadsheetgear

I have some text in cells which are formatted in different ways, let's say:
"This *is* **mixed** style ***within*** a ***single*** cell"

I can access the text content and `IRange`'s `Interior` property provides color data (among others), and `IRange` also have `Style` property which provides `Font` data, which can tell if the text is bold or italic. In my case however I may have different styles within a single cell. How can I extract that?

Comment: In VBA you would examine the `Characters` property of the `Range` object.  Is there something similar in `C#`?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Good point, there is a `GetCharacters`: http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~GetCharacters.html I'll look at `ICharacters`. It maybe not too efficient to go character-by-character, but if it works then it's fine

Comment: `ICharacters` has a `Font` property, probably this gonna work.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to suggest a solution.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld post your suggestion as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA you would examine the Characters property of the Range object. Is there something similar in C#?

Comment: C# has `GetCharacters` on the `IRange`: http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~GetCharacters.html. `ICharacters` has a `Font` property (http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/SpreadsheetGear2012~SpreadsheetGear.ICharacters_members.html) which can help with analyzing the format of any section of the content.